# Error in running GWT project

Tags: eclipse, gwt

After debugging my GWT project when i open the URL in browser ,then the following error shows in console.
Using Eclipse Kepler.

[ERROR] Unable to find 'projectName/nocache/js.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

The development shell servlet received a request to generate a host page for module 'projectName.nocache.js' 
   [ERROR] Unable to find 'projectName/nocache/js.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

'projectName.nocache.js'  filr do exist in the projectName folder .

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'After debugging'? Do you mean when you started debugging and you open de url? and could you provide information on the arguments passed to gwt dev mode and content of the main gwt.xml module you are using, the one specifying the entry point?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your module name "projectName.gwt.xml" (?) and that the entryPoint classpath is correct in there ?